# Why does the padding of one element affect the margin of another?

Tags: html, css

I have this page: http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/yU3aj/show/

If you look in the source, the CSS defines that the `<header>` should have side padding of 135px on each side, and the content should have 135px margin on each side. Why does the content end up having double that in spacing?

[image: What I see]

Comment: I don't understand/can't replicate what you mean by "double that in spacing". They both look correct to me.

Comment: That design looks strangely familiar.. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013683/css-float-and-padding "When you float an element, it's effectively taking it out of the document flow, so padding won't have an effect on it."

Comment: @Alastair: I added a picture... @thirtydot: I thought so too, but I'm having trouble putting my finger on it... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't. You're floating elements in the `<header>` and not clearing them.

Add `clear: both;` to your styles for the content `div` and it will move below the header and to the left.

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept in 3 minutes. Can't believe I missed that :P

Comment: Sometimes it just takes a different pair of eyes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine on my screen (Firefox 5.0)

Though I've read that some old IE versions have a problem called [double margin](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/doubled-margin.html)

Also make sure to put a clearfix div after those two child elements in `<header>`:

```
<header>   
  <div id="notifications" class="left">notifications</div>
  <div class="right">
    <a href="account.aspx" id="userinfo"><span class="dropdown">▾</span> username</a>
  </div>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</header>
```

EDIT: after checking out your screenshot it's obvious that you're missing that clearing div and the content below "floats after" your notifications box. Usually it is considered to be good practice to put a clearing element at the end of the floated elements, this way forcing the container to expand and "cover" all the contained elements.