# Do floated elements ignore padding?

Tags: html, css, css-float, padding

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5013712/4932834) answer states that:

> When you float an element, it's effectively taking it out of the document flow, **so adding padding to its parent won't have an effect on it**. [...]

Also [MDN states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) that:

> [...] when an element is floated it is taken out of the normal flow of the document. It is shifted to the left or right until it touches **the edge of its containing box** or another floated element.

Well, somehow, I added padding to parent element and the floated one was shifted:

```css
#a{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
}

#parent
{
    padding: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    <div id=parent>
        <div id=a></div>
    </div>
</body>


    
</html>
```

Comment: That answer probably describes some old non-standard behavior... I can't reproduce the problem described in that question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No. Floats do not ignore the padding of their container.**

The containing block of a float is established by the **content edge** of the container:

> [**10.1 Definition of "containing block"**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#containing-block-details)
>
> the containing block is formed by the content edge of the nearest
> block container ancestor box.

That content edge is affected by the padding of the container:

> [**8.1 Box dimensions**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#box-dimensions)
>
> [image]

And floats can't go to the top or to the left than their containing block.

> [**Float rules**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#float-rules)
>
> The left outer edge of a left-floating box may not be to the left of the left edge of its containing block. An analogous rule holds for right-floating elements.
>
> A floating box's outer top may not be higher than the top of its containing block.